# regex to match string not starting and/or ending with spaces but allowing inbetween spaces

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex to not match strings starting and/or ending with space(s) but matching in between spaces. I'm not an expert on regex.

I can use 2 regexes if needed.

**Note: Using `.` for showing space in examples.**

match is false for

```
 .text.
 ..text
 text..
 ..te.xt..
```

match is true for

```
 text
 te..xt
```

I came up with this. It only matches starting spaces.

```
^(?!\s+).*$
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This pattern should do the trick:

```
^\s*.*?\s*$
```

And usage:

```
Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^\s*.*?\s*$");
```

Comment: i used your original regex. but it reduces to what @scott-wegner originally mentioned and what you have now.

Comment: @hlpPy, as for me, my approach is readable and more understandable :) Maybe I just don't know some tricks...

Comment: Downvoting because `^\S+.*?\S+$` requires two non-whitespace characters, and therefore doesn't correctly match a string consisting of a single letter A for example.  `^\S(.*\S)?$` is a better expression.

Comment: This is now a totally wrong answer. `^\s*.*?\s*$` matches any string that has zero or more whitespaces on the right and left and can contain any zero or more chars other than line break chars in the middle.

Comment: Well, if you take examples from the question, the regex fulfills the requirement.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `\S` character class with the `^` and `$` anchors.

```
^\S(.*\S)?$
```

The optional `.*\S` grouping is needed to match a single non-space character.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to match what you don't want and then negate it:

```
!Regex.IsMatch(input, @"(^\s)|(\s$)")
```

Comment: @shane-andradei i had thought of this.